# Adding a summed field to a select query

Tags: mysql, sum, aggregate-functions

Assuming I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
LEFT JOIN table_b ON <conditions>
WHERE <conditions>
```

And I want to add a summed column to it, like this:

```
SELECT *, SUM(table.field)
FROM table
LEFT JOIN table_b ON <conditions>
WHERE <conditions>
```

Can it be done?

*The second query returns a single row as expected, but I need them all. and if it can be done in the same query, i prefer it.

Comment: Can you please provide output you expect? Also it's not clear why can't you run 2 queries?

Comment: It almost never makes sense to use `SELECT *` in a query containing a `JOIN` clause. Can you explain in more detail what you want your result set to contain?

Comment: did you try it in mysql and see what happens?

Comment: @IvanNevostruev - the first query returns a set of records. what i need is (probably) another column that will repeat itself and will contain the `SUM()` value.

Comment: @OllieJones - the wildcard is fine, it's two tables with very 3 columns each. some kind of log - and i need everything ... as to the result, just like i wrote here to Ivan.
"what i need is (probably) another column that will repeat itself and will contain the SUM() value" ## however, when i think of it, it makes no sense since the "query save" that i try to get, will be lost because it will have to SUM the table every row.. pointless. Unless you have an idea how it can be achieved..

Comment: When you use an aggregate function without a group by you're going to get one record (in mysql). You probably just want GROUP BY the identifying fields in "table"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't return aggregation and source data in single query. But you can run sub-query like this:

```
SELECT *, sum_query.sum_field FROM table
JOIN (SELECT sum(field) as sum_field FROM table) as sum_query
```

This is still 2 queries, but mysql will be joining results for you. Also I think code readability will suffer if you're doing things like this.